# Float type is saved as exp

Tags: c++, double, decimal, rounding

I make some calculations and the result is 
0.000137*0.000137= 0.000000018769

I save the answer in float y

but it seems to be saved as 1.88788682e-008

I want it to be saved as 0.000000018769

I tried the type double but got same answer

```
int main()
{
 float y= 0.000137*0.000137;

return 0;

}
```

y appears in the watch while debugging as 0.000137*0.000137

Comment: How do you "save" it and where? Show some code.

Comment: i mean float y = 0.000137*0.000137 @SamiKuhmonen

Comment: We cannot point out the mistake in code we cannot see.

Comment: That is not saving. That is assigning a variable. It doesn't have a textual representation by itself. Whatever you are using to show the value is doing the conversion to text. Could you tell what the actual problem is?

Comment: First, though, don't be put off by the scientific notation. That's _how your value is output to screen_, not how it's saved. Of concern though is that the values are actually different.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really have control over how floating point numbers are *stored* (which is mostly irrelevant anyway). You do have control over how they're printed though. If you want to print them out without the scientific notation, you can use `std::fixed` to get that:

```
int main() {
    float y = 0.000137*0.000137;
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(12) << y << "\n";
}
```

Result:

```
0.000000018769
```

Answer (score -1):

It is always saved equal and those numbers are equivalent

If you are printing with cout, check this reference about cout formating page

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/fixed/

Comment: In what way is 1.887886282e-8 "equivalent" to 0.000000018769?

Comment: Oh sorry, I just saw the exponential notation as difference, it is probably  float limits fault, of because your constants are doubles and then they are casted to float

Comment: There's plenty of precision in a `float` for five significant figures.